# Can't start Solr-Server after installation: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start rake aborted! undefined method `map' for :needs:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sunspot-rails

After I installed **sunspot_rails** I'm getting this error **"undefined method `map' for :needs:Symbol"** if I run **bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start**

I don't know how to pinpoint this error..
If you have any suggestions please let me know

Error:
 http://pastebin.com/5x8bKFKd

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem "sunspot_rails", "~> 1.2.1"
gem "sunspot_with_kaminari", "~> 0.1.0"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "kaminari", "~> 0.12.4"
gem "devise", ">=1.4.4"
gem "dynamic_form", "~> 1.1.4"

group :development, :test do 
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6.1"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.6.7"
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Comment: You should reformat your question so your title is a summary of the problem, not the actual error itself. Also, add some more information.  This isn't quite enough to go on. What have you tried to do to fix it?

Comment: Okay I reformat my Question. Hm I don't know what to do with that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems sunspot_rails 1.2.1 doesn't work with rails 3.2.16.
I get no error with last version of sunspot_rails

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.16'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem "sunspot_rails"
gem "sunspot_solr"
gem "sunspot_with_kaminari"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'sqlite3'
gem "kaminari", "~> 0.12.4"
gem "devise", ">=1.4.4"
gem "dynamic_form", "~> 1.1.4"

group :development, :test do 
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6.1"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.6.7"
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```